# firewall-cmd - adding 0.0.0.0/0 as a source in one zone blocks more specific access in another zone

Tags: firewalld, firewall-cmd, firewalld-zone

I have two firewalld zones configured as follows:

```
zone: ssh-access
source: 1.2.3.4
ports: 9999/tcp

zone: other-access
source: 5.6.7.8
ports: 8888/tcp
```

We temporarily want to unrestrict access to the ssh-access zone on port 9999/tcp so we replace the source so that zone is configured as follows:

```
zone: ssh-access
source: 0.0.0.0/0
ports: 9999/tcp
```

This has the desired effect for the `ssh-access` zone.

However, once we do that, the source 5.6.7.8 for zone `other-access` fails to communicate over port 8888/tcp until the `0.0.0.0/0` source for `ssh-access` is reverted back to its original value.

I feel like I'm overlooking something simple...

tl;dr: we want to allow any source to communicate over port 9999/tcp but keep it restricted to the defined source for port 8888/tcp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, perhaps somewhat obviously, this does what I want it to do.

```
firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=9999/tcp
```

It means I don't have to change anything in the `ssh-access` zone, and the public zone won't interfere with anything.

Going to call this solved now.